# How to make ./script/generate create RSpecs instead of ActionController::TestCases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I run ./script/generate scaffold Whatever, it creates ActionController::TestCase tests for me, but I prefer to use RSpec. Is there any way to get it to generate some default RSpecs for my new class instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RSpec's [own generators](http://rspec.info/rails/generators.html).